# How should I design this method in order to take a list of lambda expressions as an input?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, lambda

I have the following assignment:

> Design a class whose objects have the methods:
>
> - `setValue` which, given a String and an integer value, associates the value with the noun of the variable
> - `getValue` which returns the integer value associated with a given String
> - `execute` which invokes in sequence a given list of lambda expressions, where each one takes an instance of the class, return nothing, and act on the class through the methods *setValue* and *getValue*.

So for the example, after the following:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();

instance.execute(List.of(e -> e.setValue("x", 1),
                           e -> e.setValue("y", 2)));
```

`instance` should contain the values 1 for "x" and 2 for "y".

---

Here is what I've done so far, I think it's alright:

```
public class MyClass {

private Map<String,Integer> map;

public int getValue(String name) {return map.get(name);}

public void setValue(String name, int value) {map.put(name, value);}
```

I am not seeing the way to go for `execute`. I know I need a functional interface for those lambda expressions, but then I can't solve errors shown by Eclipse when writing `instance.execute(List.of(...))` , e.g. "The method `of(Object, Object)` in the type List is not applicable for the arguments `((<no type> e) -> {}, (<no type> e) -> {})`.
How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it backwards: If you want to call the method for a number of values, those values are the stream. Presuming you have a `Map<String, Integer>` that represents your `"x": 1` dataset, you can do this:

```
valuesMap.entrySet().stream()
    .forEach(entry -> instance.setValue(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```

Given your problem statement, though, it looks like you're being asked to do something closer to the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). In this case, you need an interface for the lambdas to implement, and there's a built-in one: [`Consumer<MyClass>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). You should get familiar with this one as well as `Supplier` and `Function`, since they're very common.

If you declare your `execute` method to take a list of these, then you can use a for loop or a stream to process them, or use the convenient built-in `forEach` method:

```
public void execute(List<Consumer<MyClass>> consumers) {
    consumers.forEach(consumer -> consumer.accept(this));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply a list of `Consumer<MyClass>`. A [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) is a functional interface with a single abstract method called `accept` which performs the action on the the given argument. Try this.

```java
public void execute(List<Consumer<MyClass>> list) {
    list.forEach(cons -> cons.accept(this));
}
```

The problem with `List::of` is that you have to either use Java 9 or you can simply do this.

```java
public void execute(Consumer<MyClass> ...list) {
    Stream.of(list).forEach(cons -> cons.accept(this));
}
```